# GC of delegates, what am I missing? (my delegate is not collected)

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, garbage-collection

I have a class that holds on to a delegate, in order to lazily evaluate something later.

Once I've evaluated it, by calling the delegate, I clear out the reference to the delegate, hoping that it would be eligible for collection. After all, it might hold on to a world of local variables if it was constructed as an anonymous method.

I tried building a unit-test to verify this, but it doesn't seem to work out the way I planned, instead it seems that either my assumptions about `WeakReference` (which I used for test purposes here), or some other assumption, doesn't hold water.

Take a look at this code, which you can run in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net)

```
void Main()
{
    WeakReference wr;
    Lazy<int> l;
    CreateTestData(out wr, out l);

    wr.IsAlive.Dump();                  // should be alive here

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    wr.IsAlive.Dump();                  // and alive here as well
    l.Value.Dump();                     // but now we clear the reference

    GC.Collect();                       // so one of these should collect it
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    wr.IsAlive.Dump();                  // and then it should be gone here
    GC.KeepAlive(l);
}

void CreateTestData(out WeakReference wr, out Lazy<int> l)
{
    Func<int> f = () => 10;
    wr = new WeakReference(f);
    l = new Lazy<int>(f);
}

public class Lazy<T>
{
    private Func<T> _GetValue;
    private T _Value;

    public Lazy(Func<T> getValue)
    {
        _GetValue = getValue;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_GetValue != null)
            {
                _Value = _GetValue();
                _GetValue = null;
            }
            return _Value;
        }
    }
}
```

I was assuming that:

1. Regardless of DEBUG build, debugger attached, since I created the delegate in a separate method, which I return from, there should be nothing holding on to the delegate, except the `WeakReference` and the `Lazy<T>` objects
2. If I ask the `Lazy<T>` object to relinquish its reference to the delegate, which would reduce the references to only the one that `WeakReference` is holding on to
3. And then force a full garbage collection, assuming that if the only reference left is the one in `WeakReference`
4. Then the delegate would be collected, and my `WeakReference` would indicate that the object is no longer alive

The output of the code was thus expected to be (with comments):

```
true  // not gc'ed after construction
true  // not gc'ed after full GC, still beind held by Lazy<T>
10    // value from calling delegate
false // but is now gc'ed, Lazy<T> no longer has a reference to it
```

But instead the output is:

```
true
true
10
true
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "problem" is that the compiler is noticing that it can reuse a single delegate instance *forever*. It doesn't capture any context, not even the implicit `this` reference. So this:

```
void CreateTestData(out WeakReference wr, out Lazy<int> l)
{
    Func<int> f = () => 10;
    ...
}
```

Is turned into something like:

```
static Func<int> hiddenDelegate;

static int HiddenMethod()
{
    return 10;
}

void CreateTestData(out WeakReference wr, out Lazy<int> l)
{
    if (hiddenDelegate == null)
    {
        hiddenDelegate = HiddenMethod;
    }

    Func<int> f = hiddenDelegate;
    ...
}
```

Look at the code in ildasm (or Reflector with no optimization turned on) to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I changed the delegate so that it used a local variable to calculate its results instead, and that was indeed collected.

Comment: Side-question: I'm assuming the compiler isn't smart enough to notice that multiple delegates, of the same type, returning the same constant value, can be created once and reused everywhere?

Comment: Basically, my goal was to have a test that verifies that the reference to the delegate is relinquished at the right times, to make it possible for garbage collection where allowed, not necessarily that that particular delegate was collected. Changing the delegate just slightly solved that problem, and tests now run as expected.

Comment: I verified it in LINQPad as well, the IL dump showed that it created a `UserQuery.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1`, exactly like you said.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Sorry for the delay in answering. No, the compiler doesn't (currently) try to coalesce multiple lambda expressions which have the same code. The tests for functional equivalence could get tricky.